# How to fix an error "access to the path denied" in the hosted application in IIS

Tags: vb.net, file-access

My application involves in deleting a file from TFS Source control explorer and moving the newly created file to the deleted file path. It is properly working when i am running it locally, I hosted this application in a server machine but it is throwing me an error saying "access to the path denied" when it comes to the delete functionality of the file.

I have tried the following.

1) Added IIS_IUSRS identity with FullControl access for the file security property.
2) Enabled the Directory Browsing for the website in IIS server.
3) Tried creating a user account to run the app pool.

but no luck. I am getting the same error. Please suggest me something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: would it be possible to see the code? did you try run as admin?

Comment: Sorry i amn't getting:(...Admin in what?

Comment: Private Sub MoveTheChangesToTFS(fileName As String, updatedScriptFilePath As String)

File.Delete(fileName) --> Getting an error at this point
File.Move(updatedScriptFilePath, fileName)

End Sub                                                                                                                        and the file resides in F:

Comment: edit your main post [mcve]

Comment: sounds like the file is being read by something already, we would need to see your code to make sure this isn't happening.

Comment: this file will be checkout first and once it is replaced with the new file checkin will happen. The above is the code where i am getting an error.